# Convert SQL cmd statement to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, stored-procedures

I have a `.BAT` file that contains a SQL statement. And I am not understanding how to convert this to a stored procedure.

This is the statement:

```
 ECHO 2, MDCESS_TRAKG_NUM, 1 , 2, dropoff, 3, 4, ORDER_NUM, MERCHANT_ORDER_NUM, MASTER_BARCODE, BARCODE, SERIAL_NUM, 5, NET_WEIGHT, GROSS_WEIGHT, DIM_WEIGHT, DRIVER, TRAILER, DELIVERY_DATE >\\c:\\Manifest.txt

SQLCMD -S SQLSERVEREXPRESS -d MyDb -U sa -P triple -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON select  2 AS '2', ORDE_.billgrp AS ENSENDA_TRAKG_NUM, 1 AS '1', 2 AS '2', dropoff AS dropoff, 3 AS '3', 4 AS '4', orde_.ordernum AS ORDER_NUM, CASE WHEN (Left(daddr,11)='1955 VAUGHN' AND READYDATE=CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),112)) THEN 'TBLK_ATL_'+ DRV1NUM + '_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),10) ,'-', '') ELSE left(orde_.ref, 18) END AS MERCHANGE_ORDER_NUM, GFIELD4 AS MASTER_BARCODE, CASE WHEN orde_.CLIENTNUM in ('CDSLOG45', 'NEWAGE20', 'ENATLPEL') THEN orde_.BILLGRP ELSE GFIELD2 END AS BARCODE, left(GFIELD3,30) AS SERIAL_NUM, 5 AS '5', isnull(INVNUM,0) AS NET_WEIGHT,isnull(INVNUM,0) AS GROSS_WEIGHT,isnull(INVNUM,0) AS DIM_WEIGHT, orde_.DRV1NUM AS DRIVER, orde_.CALLER AS TRAILER, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), orde_.READYDATE, 120) AS DELIVERY_DATE FROM GENERICFIELDS FULL OUTER JOIN ORDE_ ON GENERICFIELDS.ORDERID=ORDE_.ORDERID FULL OUTER JOIN CLIENT ON ORDE_.CLIENTID=CLIENT.CLIENTID WHERE orde_.droptime is null and (GFIELD2 is not null or orde_.CLIENTNUM in ('CDSLOG45', 'NEWAGE20', 'ENATLPEL') ) and ORDE_.CANCELLED='0' and dispid in ('65')" -h-1 -b -o "\\ADV\SCANNERMANIFEST.TXT" -s "," -W

copy \\intro\Atlanta5\*.txt \\intro\My.txt /y /b

del \\intro\My.csv

ren \\intro\My.txt My.csv
```

Can you please tell me how I can convert this to a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xp_cmdshell for executing all the copy, delete and rename after executing sql query

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'copy \\intro\Atlanta5\*.txt \\intro\My.txt /y /b';
```

To copy the data from sql server you can try bcp out utility like below:

```
bcp "SELECT * from table " queryout D:\BCP\output.txt  -t, -c -T,-S SQLSERVER-d MyDb -U sa -P triple
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. i m in problem with  SQLCMD Line how can i rewrite that line in sp

Comment: Why you require sqlcmd in SQL sproc? You can directly ecexute SQL command in sproc rite? Am I understanding different here?

Comment: Kandasamy actually i want to write the value to text file that is returning from my select statement. And i need to do this from store procedure

Comment: Kandasamy i want to do this from SProce. but dont know how can i do the same thing from Sprocedure

Comment: I use bcp and working for me. you add the bcp with text file and i will upvote your answer

Comment: i hv edit your answer and upvote your answer. Plz upvote my question if you like this